# куча варнингов, после обновления в браузере vue devtools

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, google-chrome-devtools

Сделал обновление расширения vue devtols в браузере (ничего не обновилось, стояла последняя версия, попытался обновить потому что в проекте перестало видеть расширение) и теперь во vue проекте вылазит куча removings, как их убрать не знаю. Сделал rollback в проекте, переустановил vue devtols - не помогло. Если открыть другой проект на vue, консоль в таких же ошибках. При этом проекты работают исправно, но консоль измазана в желтом. Никогда с подобным не сталкивался. Знает кто - в чем причина, как исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

не знаю, как это вообще возможно, но оказалось, что если отключить в браузере расширение криптокошелька, то вся желтизна исчезает.
Как это связалось всё, как соотнеслось, остается загадкой века, потрачено шесть часов...